# Can I force finder to open without loading previous files?

Tags: macos, finder, crash

Finder crashed recently and I had to force quit it. Problem is that now when I open something with it, all of the files that it had open previously (including the one that caused the crash) try and open, and it crashes again. Is there a way to force Finder to open (one time only) as a clean slate?

Comment: Why not just close them then?

Comment: Finder hangs as soon as it tries to open the files, because one of the past files caused it to crash.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the savedState directory:

```
rm -r ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.finder.savedState/
```

When I tried running `killall -kill Finder`, that worked, but `open -Fa Finder` or command-clicking Finder's Dock icon didn't.

You could also try to:

- Disable `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Finder.plist` by temporarily moving it somewhere else.
- Cause a kernel panic with `sudo dtrace -w -n 'BEGIN{panic();}'`. There is normally an option to disable restoring state after kernel panics.
- Temporarily unload the launchd agent with `launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.Finder.plist`. There is normally a dialog about restoring state after crashes, but maybe it's not shown if the program is opened by launchd.

Comment: Tried all three - still loading up everything including the crashed file. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: I edited the post to add three more things you could try. If there are any relevant log messages, you could also edit the question to include them.